# Copying files from _PublishedWebsites to $(_PackageTempDir)

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I have a web app and a Azure web job (Console application) built and located in a Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) drop folder. Structure below

```
- drop
 -- _PublishedWebsites
  --- Site
  --- WebJob
```

I need to copy the console apps bin folder into the $(_PackageTempDir).

```
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
```

I have been using the below in a webjobs.props file which is being run but it isn't copying anything.

```
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\WebJob\bin\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="AdditionalFilesForPackage" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\app_data\jobs\triggered\WebJobName" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or vNext build?

Comment: Did you specify the outdir in MSBuild argument in your definition? Is the copy action executed in another build step, not the step with outdir specified?